# How can two variables both be a JQuery object, yet .css property not work on one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, how can `thebody` and `app.body` both be a JQuery object, yet setting the `.css` property on `thebody` works but does not work on `app.body`?

```
var app = app || {};

app.show = function(html) {
    this.baseElement.html(html);
};

app.body = $('body');

app.init = function() {
    this.baseElement = $('div#app');
    var thebody = $('body');
    console.log(app.objectIsJquery(thebody)); //true
    console.log(app.objectIsJquery(app.body)); //true
    app.body.css('background-color', 'yellow'); //does not set the background color, no errors
    //thebody.css('background-color', 'yellow'); //sets color correctly
};

app.start = function() {
    this.baseElement.css('color', 'brown');
    this.show(dp.qstr.addStar('testing'));
};


app.objectIsJquery = function(obj) {
    return obj.selector != undefined;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  - `this.body` instead of `app.body`?

Comment: this.body doesn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is likely in the head section of your page. So when the line `app.body = $('body');` is executed, the body doesn't exist yet. But then you call `app.init()` later; probably on DOMReady, so the body exists at that point. When you run `var thebody = $('body');` you get one element in the collection.

You can verify this by checking if `app.body.length === 0` while `thebody.length === 1`.

You should either move that entire block of code into the body or into a `DOMReady` callback like:

```
$(function(){

...

});
```

Comment: that was it, I put my script elements at the bottom of the body and it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.body.html().css()
```

If my hunch is right, your jquery is not selecting the dom of app.body and hence you need to translate it to html for selecting it.

Comment: `app.body.html().css('background-color', 'yellow');` gives me "app.body.html() is null"

Comment: I see, then maybe it is how you set up your structure. When you do app.body = $('body'); you are basically selecting the body and storing it in a variable. In this case app->body. Where as when you do thebody = $('body') you are storing it in that variable and then when you assign it a background it is not being stored in a object. That is my wild hypothesis. Hope it helps!